# Calculation of ${\rm E}[e^X]$ where $X$ follows a uniform distribution over $(1,2)$

Tags: statistics

To compute ${\rm E}[e^X]$, in which $X$ has uniform $U(1,2)$ distribution. Here $f(x)=1$ for $x\in (1,2)$.

The formula is $\int_0^1 e^x \,\mathrm dx$. Is the answer $e^2 - e^1$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer is $e^2-e^1$, but the formula should be $\int_1^2 e^x\,\mathrm dx$ and not $\int_0^1 e^x\,\mathrm dx$ as you have written. The answer also agrees with [the moment generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29#Moment-generating_function) of an $U(1,2)$ distribution evaluated at $t=1$.